# Will this digital signing code work with a Qualified Digital Certificate?

Tags: c++, cryptography, digital-signature

I was recently asked if our existing signing code will work with a [European Qualified Digital Certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qualified_digital_certificate) in place of the RSA signing certificate we normally use. As far as I can tell it should, but I haven't found anything that actually confirms this theory.

Short of figuring out how to acquire a qualified certificate and actually testing it, I'm not sure how to answer this question definitively. Anybody happen to have experience with this?

The code in question is shown below. It's a Windows-based C++ application that is using Microsoft's Cryptographic API for signing.

```
int SignData(
    const std::string &data,        // Data to be signed
    const char *containerName,      // Name of key container to use
    std::string &signature)         // Returns the signature
{
    HCRYPTPROV hProv = NULL;
    HCRYPTHASH hHash = NULL;
    HCRYPTKEY hKey = NULL;
    DWORD dwLength;
    int status = 0;

    // Attempt to open the key container as a LocalMachine key.
    if (CryptAcquireContext(
        &hProv,
        containerName,
        NULL,
        PROV_RSA_FULL,
        CRYPT_MACHINE_KEYSET | CRYPT_SILENT))
    {
        // Create a SHA-1 hash context.
        if (CryptCreateHash(hProv, CALG_SHA1, 0, 0, &hHash))
        {
            // Calculate hash of the buffer.
            if (CryptHashData(hHash, (const BYTE *)data.data(), (DWORD)data.size(), 0))
            {
                // Determine the size of the signature and allocate memory.
                if (CryptSignHash(hHash, AT_SIGNATURE, 0, 0, NULL, &dwLength))
                {
                    signature.resize(dwLength);

                    // Sign the hash object.
                    if (!CryptSignHash(hHash, AT_SIGNATURE, 0, 0, (BYTE*)&signature[0], &dwLength))
                        status = HandleCryptError("CryptSignHash failed");
                }
                else
                    status = HandleCryptError("CryptSignHash failed");
            }
            else
                status = HandleCryptError("CryptHashData failed");
        }
        else
            status = HandleCryptError("CryptCreateHash failed");
    }
    else
        status = HandleCryptError("CryptAcquireContext failed");

    return status;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above code is using the default Microsoft software cryptographic provider which doesn't meet the requirements of eIDAS.

If you replace the default Microsoft provider by an eIDAS compliant provider in the above code then this approach of performing signature is OK. Under the hood, the compliant CSP will take care of non-repudiation requirement of the key usage, for example by displaying a PIN popup or if the key is stored remotely in a server by sending a 2FA notification to the key owner.